# Method with UIDynamicItemBehavior works locally but not when called from another class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidynamicanimator

When I call this method locally, the animation works fine. When it's called from another class however, I get a Thread 1 SIGABRT error: "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'"

```
- (void)test{

animator = [[UIDynamicAnimator alloc] initWithReferenceView:self.view];

settings_snap_behaviour = [[UISnapBehavior alloc] initWithItem:_orange_ball snapToPoint:CGPointMake(64, 237)];

UIDynamicItemBehavior *ballBehavior = [[UIDynamicItemBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[_orange_ball]];

ballBehavior.elasticity = 1.0;

[animator addBehavior:ballBehavior];

[animator addBehavior:settings_snap_behaviour];

}
```

The actual method call is working, as I replaced the guts of the method with an NSLog and it worked fine. From my testing, it seems to be specifically related to initWithItems:@[_orange_ball]

Why would it work locally but not when called from another class? I think I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: What is _orange_ball? Try to set up a breakpoint when calling from another class and look into all objects in scope. Some of them might not be initialised (self.view or _orange_ball). When you get an error there should be a more specific description of NSException, post it here.

Comment: @NKorotkov _orange_ball is a UIImageView. I'll try what you suggested now.

Comment: @NKorotkov 2015-06-25 02:01:28.845 Temperature Monitor[40548:3355635] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'

Comment: `initWithItems:@[_orange_ball]` seems to be the problem here. Have you tried breakpoint thing? Exception clearly says that you are trying to insert nil object into array, probably _orange_ball is nil.